# QR decomposition different in lm and biglm?

Tags: r, matrix, lm, qr-decomposition

I'm trying to recover the R matrix from the QR decomposition used in biglm. For this I am using a portion of the code in vcov.biglm and put it into a function like so:

```
qr.R.biglm <- function (object, ...) {
    # Return the qr.R matrix from a biglm object
    object$qr <- .Call("singcheckQR", object$qr)
    p <- length(object$qr$D)
    R <- diag(p)
    R[row(R) > col(R)] <- object$qr$rbar
    R <- t(R)
    R <- sqrt(object$qr$D) * R
    dimnames(R) <- list(object$names, object$names)
    return(R)
}
```

More specifically, I'm trying to get the same result as using qr.R from the base package, which is used on QR decompositions of class "qr" such as those contained in the lm class (lm$qr). The code for the base function is as follows:

```
qr.R <- function (qr, complete = FALSE) {
    if (!is.qr(qr)) 
        stop("argument is not a QR decomposition")
    R <- qr$qr
    if (!complete) 
        R <- R[seq.int(min(dim(R))), , drop = FALSE]
    R[row(R) > col(R)] <- 0
    R
}
```

I manage to get the same result for a sample regression, except for the signs.

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100 * 10), 100, 10))
y <- seq.int(1, 100)
fit.lm <- lm("y ~ .", data =  cbind(y, x))
R.lm <- qr.R(fit.lm$qr)

library(biglm)
fmla <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(colnames(x), collapse = "+")))
fit.biglm <- biglm(fmla, data = cbind(y, x))
R.biglm <- qr.R.biglm(fit.biglm)
```

Comparing both, it's clear that the absolute values match, but not the signs.

```
mean(abs(R.lm) - abs(R.biglm) < 1e-6)
[1] 1
mean(R.lm - R.biglm < 1e-6)
[1] 0.9338843
```

I can't quite figure out why this is. I would like to be able to get the same result for the R matrix as lm from biglm.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two R matrices is that **biglm** apparently performs its rotations such that R's diagonal elements are all positive, while **lm** (or, really, the routines it calls) imposes no such constraint. (There should be no numerical advantage to one strategy or the other, so the difference is just one of convention, AFAIKT.)

You can make **lm**'s results identical to **biglm**'s by imposing that additional constraint yourself. I'd use a reflection matrix that multiplies columns by either 1 or -1, such that the diagonal elements all end up positive:

```
## Apply the necessary reflections
R.lm2 <- diag(sign(diag(R.lm))) %*% R.lm

## Show that they did the job
mean(R.lm2 - R.biglm < 1e-6)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. That's useful. However, I'm trying to solve the opposite problem: how can I make the biglm R matrix match the lm R matrix? If it's possible.

Comment: @user3327 -- OK. I guess I misunderstood the final sentence of your post. I won't be able to help any farther, but will leave this up in case someone else is interested... Just out of curiosity, why do you care that the signs of the columns of the two R matrices match?

Comment: Thanks Josh. Just to give a little bit more background: I'm trying to replace `lm` for `biglm` in some existing code, as I have a large data set I want to perform regression on and will not be able to use `lm`. My program uses this R matrix further down the line and it would be nice if I can simply extract the same matrix, as opposed to having to come up with a new formula. If it does come to that, so be it :-) just thought I'd ask around first.