# QR decomposition and Choleski decomposition in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra, decomposition, qr-decomposition

I recently read about how the R matrix of QR decomposition can be calculated using the Choleski decomposition. The relation is:

> R = Choleski-decomposition(A^TA)

Example:

```
> A=matrix(c(1,2,3,2,3,5,1,3,2), nrow=3)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    1
[2,]    2    3    3
[3,]    3    5    2

> AtA = t(A)%*%A
> AtA
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   14   23   13
[2,]   23   38   21
[3,]   13   21   14
```

Now calculating QR and Choleski decomposition:

```
> chol(AtA)
         [,1]     [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 3.741657 6.147009  3.4743961
[2,] 0.000000 0.462910 -0.7715167
[3,] 0.000000 0.000000  1.1547005

> qr_A = qr(A)
> qr.R(qr_A)
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -3.741657 -6.147009 -3.4743961
[2,]  0.000000  0.462910 -0.7715167
[3,]  0.000000  0.000000 -1.1547005
```

As observed, the values of the R matrix calculated from Choleski and QR decomposition are not the same. The first and the third rows of `chol(AtA)` are negated w.r.t `qr.R(qr_A)`. Why is that? Is the relation I'm assuming not correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QR-decomposition of a matrix is not unique! There is a QR-decomposition with R=chol(AtA), but there are also others and `qr` does not necessairily give that one. In your example

```
qr.Q(qr_A)%*%qr.R(qr_A)
```

and

```
(qr.Q(qr_A)%*%diag(c(-1,1,-1)))%*%chol(AtA)
```

are both valid QR-decompositions of A.

Comment: Exactly. And for some more details, [see this excellent answer](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/seemingly-non-unique-cholesky-factor-via-qr-rectangularisation/1104#1104), given when the exact same question was posed over on the Computational Science SO beta.

Comment: Great. Thanks! Are there QR decomposition implementations in R that will definitely give me a positive diagonal?

Comment: @PrateekKulkarni -- [As discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248960/qr-decomposition-different-in-lm-and-biglm/13252584#13252584), the R package **biglm** seems to use an implementation that does what you're asking for.