# Why the built-in lm function is so slow in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I always thought that the `lm` function was extremely fast in R, but as this example would suggest, the closed solution computed using the `solve` function is way faster.

```
data<-data.frame(y=rnorm(1000),x1=rnorm(1000),x2=rnorm(1000))
X = cbind(1,data$x1,data$x2)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
solve(t(X) %*% X, t(X) %*% data$y),
lm(y ~ .,data=data))
```

Can someone explain me if this toy example is a bad example or it is the case that `lm` is actually slow?

EDIT: As suggested by Dirk Eddelbuettel, as `lm` needs to resolve the formula, the comparison is unfair, so better to use `lm.fit` which doesn't need to resolve the formula

```
microbenchmark(
solve(t(X) %*% X, t(X) %*% data$y),
lm.fit(X,data$y))


Unit: microseconds
                           expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
solve(t(X) %*% X, t(X) %*% data$y)  99.083 108.754 125.1398 118.0305 131.2545 236.060   100  a 
                      lm.fit(X, y) 125.136 136.978 151.4656 143.4915 156.7155 262.114   100   b
```

Comment: Remember that `lm()` is doing a lot more than solving the least squares problem. The list generated by `lm()` has 12 items.

Comment: Please show the output for the benchmarks. That way others don't need to run them and they are preserved if later versions of the stats package change this.

Comment: your edit doesn't make sense.  If you want to use `lm.fit()` you need `lm.fit(X,data$y)` -- which is much closer to `solve` in this case, although the mean is still *slightly* larger.

Comment: I could, but it seems slower. You want me to do it anyway?

Comment: @jogo Yes better to change just the first expression

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are overlooking that

- `solve()` only returns your parameters
- `lm()` returns you a (very rich) object with *many* components for subsequent analysis, inference, plots, ...
- the main cost of your `lm()` call is **not** the projection but the resolution of the formula `y ~ .` from which the model matrix needs to be built.

To illustrate Rcpp we wrote a few variants of a function `fastLm()` doing more of what `lm()` does (ie a bit more than `lm.fit()` from base R) and measured it.  See e.g. [this benchmark script](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/examples/fastLm.r) which clearly shows that *the dominant cost for smaller data sets is in parsing the formula and building the model matrix*.

In short, you are doing the *Right Thing* by using benchmarking but you are doing it not all that correctly in trying to compare what is mostly incomparable: a subset with a much larger task.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Actually, using the `lm.fit` (which I suppose doesn't need to resolve the formula), the gap is hugely reduced. Do you think the only difference left is now due to just the computation of all the other elements?

Comment: Yes it is as benchmarking would confirm :)   If you like the answer please feel free to accept it (by clicking on the 'tick mark'; clicking on the 'up arrow' to vote for it is also welcome).

Comment: You definitely need both :) Just one more thing, I'm trying to performing some linear algebra to show how to speed up the computation of the least squares, what would be a way to compare the computation using the linear algebra to the faster version to `lm`? I don't know if the call to the C code of `lm` needs to return all the other elements.

Comment: AFAIK the QR-decomposition used to do the linear algebra in lm() is FORTRAN-code.

Answer (score 19):

**Something wrong with your benchmarking**

It is really surprising that no one observed this!

You have used `t(X) %*% X` inside `solve()`. You should use `crossprod(X)`, as `X'X` is a symmetric matrix. `crossprod()` only computes half of the matrix while copying the rest. `%*%` forces computing all. So `crossprod()` will be two times faster. This explains why in your benchmarking, you have roughly the same timing between `solve()` and `lm.fit()`.

On my old Intel Nahalem (2008 Intel Core 2 Duo), I have:

```
X <- matrix(runif(1000*1000),1000)
system.time(t(X)%*%X)
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.320   0.000   2.079 
system.time(crossprod(X))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.22    0.00    0.94
```

If your computer is faster, try using `X <- matrix(runif(2000*2000),2000)` instead.

In the following, I will explain the computational details involved in all fitting methods.

---

**QR factorization v.s. Cholesky factorization**

`lm()` / `lm.fit()` is QR based, while `solve()` is Cholesky based. The computational costs of QR decomposition is `2 * n * p^2`, while Cholesky method is `n * p^2 + p^3` (`n * p^2` for computing matrix cross product, `p^3` for Cholesky decomposition). So you can see that when `n` is much much greater than `p`, Cholesky method is about 2 times faster than QR method. So there is really no need to benchmark here. (*in case you don't know, `n` is the number of data, `p` is the number of parameters.*)

---

**LINPACK QR v.s. LAPACK QR**

Typically, `lm.fit()` uses (modified) `LINPACK` QR factorization algorithm, rather than `LAPACK` QR factorization algorithm. Maybe you are not very familiar with `BLAS/LINPACK/LAPACK`; these are FORTRAN code providing kernel scientific matrix computations. `LINPACK` calls level-1 BLAS, while `LAPACK` calls level-3 `BLAS` using block algorithms. On average, `LAPACK` QR is 1.6 times faster than `LINPACK` QR. **The critical reason that `lm.fit()` does not use `LAPACK` version, is the need for partial column pivoting.** `LAPACK` version does full column pivoting, making it more difficult for `summary.lm()` to use the `R` matrix factor of QR decomposition to produce F-statistic and `ANOVA` test.

---

**pivoting v.s. no pivoting**

`fastLm()` from `RcppEigen` package uses `LAPACK` non-pivoted QR factorization. Again, you may be unclear about the QR factorization algorithm and pivoting issues. You only need to know that QR factorization with pivoting has only 50% share of level-3 `BLAS`, while QR factorization without pivoting has 100% share of level-3 `BLAS`. In this regard, giving up pivoting will speed up QR factorization process. Surely, the final result is different, and when the model matrix is rank deficient, no pivoting gives dangerous result.

There is a good question related to the different result you get from `fastLM`: [Why does `fastLm()` return results when I run a regression with one observation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37656722/4891738). @BenBolker, @DirkEddelbuettel and I had a very brief discussion in comments of Ben's answer.

---

**Conclusion: Do you want speed, or numerical stability?**

In terms of numerical stability, there is:

```
LINPACK pivoted QR > LAPACK pivoted QR > pivoted Cholesky > LAPACK non-pivoted QR
```

In terms of speed, there is:

```
LINPACK pivoted QR < LAPACK pivoted QR < pivoted Cholesky < LAPACK non-pivoted QR
```

As Dirk said,

> *FWIW the RcppEigen package has a fuller set of decompositions in its `fastLm()` example. But here it is as Ben so eloquently stated: "this is part of the price you pay for speed.". We give you enough rope to hang yourself. If you want to protect yourself from yourself, stick with `lm()` or `lm.fit()`, or create a hybrid 'fast-but-safe' version.*

---

**Fast and stable version**

Check [my answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38604244/4891738).