# Why does `fastLm()` return results when I run a regression with one observation?

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

Why does `fastLm()` return results when I run regressions with one observation?

In the following, why aren't the `lm()` and `fastLm()` results equal?

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(y = rnorm(5), x1 = rnorm(5), x2 = rnorm(5), my.key = 1:5)
#             y         x1         x2 my.key
# 1: -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812      1
# 2:  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432      2
# 3: -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406      3
# 4:  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999      4
# 5:  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309      5

lm(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2, data = DT[my.key == 1])
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x1           x2  
#     -0.6265           NA           NA

fastLm(X = model.matrix(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2, data = DT[my.key == 1]), y = DT[my.key == 1]$y)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          x1          x2 
#    -0.15825     0.12984    -0.23924 

model.matrix(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2, data = DT[my.key == 1])
#   (Intercept)        x1       x2
#             1 -0.8204684 1.511781
# attr(,"assign")
# [1] 0 1 2

DT[my.key == 1]$y
# [1] -0.6264538
```

When I use the whole `DT` the results are equal:

```
 all.equal(fastLm(X = model.matrix(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2, data = DT), y = DT$y)$coef, 
           lm.fit(x = model.matrix(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2, data = DT), y = DT$y)$coef)
# [1] TRUE
```

From the `RcppArmadillo` library with a modified [fLmTwoCasts](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/examples/fastLm.r) I also get the same behavior:

```
src <- '
Rcpp::List fLmTwoCastsOnlyCoefficients(Rcpp::NumericMatrix Xr, Rcpp::NumericVector yr) {
    int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();
    arma::mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false);
    arma::colvec y(yr.begin(), yr.size(), false);
    arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);
    return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("coefficients")=trans(coef));
}
'
cppFunction(code=src, depends="RcppArmadillo")

XX <- model.matrix(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2, data = DT[my.key == 1])
YY <- DT[my.key == 1]$y
fLmTwoCastsOnlyCoefficients(XX, YY)$coef
#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
# [1,] -0.1582493 0.1298386 -0.2392384
```

Using the whole `DT` the coefficients are identical as they should:

```
lm(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2, data = DT)$coef
# (Intercept)          x1          x2 
#   0.2587933  -0.7709158  -0.6648270

XX.whole <- model.matrix(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2, data = DT)
YY.whole <- DT$y
fLmTwoCastsOnlyCoefficients(XX.whole, YY.whole)
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 0.2587933 -0.7709158 -0.664827
```

Comment: "However, Armadillo will either fail or, worse, produce completely incorrect answers on rank-deficient model matrices whereas the functions from the stats package will handle them properly due to the modified Linpack code."

Answer (score 6):

Because `fastLm` doesn't worry about rank-deficiency; this is part of the price you pay for speed.

From `?fastLm`:

> ... The reason that Armadillo can do something like lm.fit faster than the functions in the stats package is because Armadillo uses the Lapack version of the QR decomposition while the stats package uses a modified Linpack version. Hence Armadillo uses level-3 BLAS code whereas the stats package uses level-1 BLAS. However, Armadillo will either fail or, worse, produce completely incorrect answers on rank-deficient model matrices whereas the functions from the stats package will handle them properly due to the modified Linpack code.

Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/82d8a3a922fc158f2403b233b2ac6861c538d514/inst/examples/Attributes/Depends.cpp), the guts of the code are

```
 arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);
```

This does a QR decomposition.  We can match the `lmFast` results with `qr()` from base R (here I am not using only base R constructs rather than relying on `data.table`):

```
set.seed(1)
dd <- data.frame(y = rnorm(5), 
      x1 = rnorm(5), x2 = rnorm(5), my.key = 1:5)

X <- model.matrix(~1+x1+x2, data=subset(dd,my.key==1))
qr(X,dd$y)
## $qr
##   (Intercept)         x1       x2
## 1           1 -0.8204684 1.511781
```

You can look at the code of `lm.fit()` to see what R does about rank deficiency when fitting linear models; the underlying BLAS algorithm it calls does QR with pivoting ...

If you want to flag these situations, I think that `Matrix::rankMatrix()` will do the trick:

```
library(Matrix)
rankMatrix(X) < ncol(X)  ## TRUE
X1 <- model.matrix(~1+x1+x2, data=dd)
rankMatrix(X1) < ncol(X1)  ## FALSE
```

Comment: Hopefully, this is the only reason, right? So if I check the definiteness of X'X will prevent me for considering such cases. That is, `library(matrixcalc); is.positive.definite(crossprod(XX))` is `FALSE`, while `is.positive.definite(crossprod(XX))` is `TRUE`, in which case I do not consider the first case (XX has only one observation, while XX.whole 5).

Comment: I assume not, but I don't know.  Here's the documentation for `arma::solve` ... http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#solve

Comment: FWIW the RcppEigen package has a fuller set of decompositions in its `fastLm()` example.  But here it is as Ben so eloquently stated: _"this is part of the price you pay for speed."_.  We give you enough rope to hang yourself.  If you want to protect yourself from yourself, stick with `lm()` or `lm.fit()`, or create a hybrid 'fast-but-safe' version.