# Fit many formulae at once, faster options than lapply?

Tags: r, vectorization, lm

I have a list for formulas I want to fit to data, rather than running a loop I'd like to do this at once, for performance's sake. The estimations should still be separate, I'm not trying to estimate a SUR or anything.
The following code does what I want

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(300),ncol=3)
y <- x %*% c(1,2,3)+rnorm(100)
formulae <-list(y~x[,1],
                y~x[,2],
                y~x[,1] + x[,2])
lapply(formulae,lm)
```

Unfortunately this gets somewhat slow as the length of `formulae` increases is there a way to truly vectorize this?

If it is any help, the only results of `lm` I care about are coefficients, and some standard errors.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified that. I meant, these are the only results I care about, basically what I get when I do `summary(results)$coefficients`

Comment: Not entirely sure I get what you're saying

Comment: You could always try to use parallelization

Comment: There is always RcppEigen::fastLm

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80888/using-the-normal-equations-to-calculate-coefficients-in-multiple-linear-regressi)

Answer (score 5):

As I said in my comment, what you really need is a more efficient yet stable fitting routine other than `lm()`. Here I would provide you a well tested one written myself, called `lm.chol()`. It takes a `formula` and `data`, and returns:

- a coefficient summary table, as you normally see in `summary(lm(...))$coef`;
- Pearson estimate of residual standard error, as you get from `summary(lm(...))$sigma`;
- adjusted-R.squared, as you get from `summary(lm(...))$adj.r.squared`.

---

```
## linear model estimation based on pivoted Cholesky factorization with Jacobi preconditioner
lm.chol <- function(formula, data) {
  ## stage0: get response vector and model matrix
  ## we did not follow the normal route: match.call, model.frame, model.response, model matrix, etc
  y <- data[[as.character(formula[[2]])]]
  X <- model.matrix(formula, data)
  n <- nrow(X); p <- ncol(X)
  ## stage 1: XtX and Jacobi diagonal preconditioner
  XtX <- crossprod(X)
  D <- 1 / sqrt(diag(XtX))
  ## stage 2: pivoted Cholesky factorization
  R <- suppressWarnings(chol(t(D * t(D * XtX)), pivot = TRUE))
  piv <- attr(R, "pivot")
  r <- attr(R, "rank")
  if (r < p) {
    warning("Model is rank-deficient!")
    piv <- piv[1:r]
    R <- R[1:r, 1:r]
    }
  ## stage 3: solve linear system for coefficients
  D <- D[piv]
  b <- D * crossprod(X, y)[piv]
  z <- forwardsolve(t(R), b)
  RSS <- sum(y * y) - sum(z * z)
  sigma <- sqrt(RSS / (n - r))
  para <- D * backsolve(R, z)
  beta.hat <- rep(NA, p)
  beta.hat[piv] <- para
  ## stage 4: get standard error
  Rinv <- backsolve(R, diag(r))
  se <- rep(NA, p)
  se[piv] <- D * sqrt(rowSums(Rinv * Rinv)) * sigma
  ## stage 5: t-statistic and p-value
  t.statistic <- beta.hat / se
  p.value <- 2 * pt(-abs(t.statistic), df = n - r)
  ## stage 6: construct coefficient summary matrix
  coefficients <- matrix(c(beta.hat, se, t.statistic, p.value), ncol = 4L)
  colnames(coefficients) <- c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "t value", "Pr(>|t|)")
  rownames(coefficients) <- colnames(X)
  ## stage 7: compute adjusted R.squared
  adj.R2 <- 1 - sigma * sigma / var(y)
  ## return model fitting results
  attr(coefficients, "sigma") <- sigma
  attr(coefficients, "adj.R2") <- adj.R2
  coefficients
  }
```

Here I would offer three examples.

---

**Example 1: full rank linear model**

We take R's built-in dataset `trees` as an example.

```
# using `lm()`
summary(lm(Height ~ Girth + Volume, trees))
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  83.2958     9.0866   9.167 6.33e-10 ***
#Girth        -1.8615     1.1567  -1.609   0.1188    
#Volume        0.5756     0.2208   2.607   0.0145 *  
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#Residual standard error: 5.056 on 28 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.4123,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.3703 
#F-statistic:  9.82 on 2 and 28 DF,  p-value: 0.0005868

## using `lm.chol()`
lm.chol(Height ~ Girth + Volume, trees)
#              Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) 83.2957705  9.0865753  9.166905 6.333488e-10
#Girth       -1.8615109  1.1566879 -1.609346 1.187591e-01
#Volume       0.5755946  0.2208225  2.606594 1.449097e-02
#attr(,"sigma")
#[1] 5.056318
#attr(,"adj.R2")
#[1] 0.3702869
```

The results are exactly the same!

---

**Example 2: rank-deficient linear model**

```
## toy data
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), x1 = runif(100), x2 = rbeta(100,3,5))
dat$x3 <- with(dat, (x1 + x2) / 2)

## using `lm()`
summary(lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, dat))
#Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)   0.2164     0.2530   0.856    0.394
#x1           -0.1526     0.3252  -0.469    0.640
#x2           -0.3534     0.5707  -0.619    0.537
#x3                NA         NA      NA       NA

#Residual standard error: 0.8886 on 97 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.0069,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.01358 
#F-statistic: 0.337 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 0.7147

## using `lm.chol()`
lm.chol(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, dat)
#              Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)  0.2164455  0.2529576  0.8556595 0.3942949
#x1                  NA         NA         NA        NA
#x2          -0.2007894  0.6866871 -0.2924030 0.7706030
#x3          -0.3051760  0.6504256 -0.4691944 0.6399836
#attr(,"sigma")
#[1] 0.8886214
#attr(,"adj.R2")
#[1] -0.01357594
#Warning message:
#In lm.chol(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, dat) : Model is rank-deficient!
```

Here, `lm.chol()` based on Cholesky factorization with complete pivoting and `lm()` based on QR factorization with partial pivoting have shrunk different coefficients to `NA`. But two estimation are equivalent, with the same fitted values and residuals.

---

**Example 3: performance for large linear models**

```
n <- 10000; p <- 300
set.seed(0)
dat <- as.data.frame(setNames(replicate(p, rnorm(n), simplify = FALSE), paste0("x",1:p)))
dat$y <- rnorm(n)

## using `lm()`
system.time(lm(y ~ ., dat))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  3.212   0.096   3.315

## using `lm.chol()`
system.time(lm.chol(y ~ ., dat))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.024   0.028   1.056
```

`lm.chol()` is 3 ~ 4 times faster than `lm()`. If you want to know the reason, read [my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37919817/4891738).

---

**Remark**

I have focused on improving performance on computational kernel. You can take one step further, by using Ben Bolker's parallelism suggestion. If my approach gives 3 times boost, and parallel computing gives 3 times boost on 4 cores, you end up with 9 times boost!

Answer (score 4):

There's not really an easy way to vectorize this, but the `pdredge` function from the `MuMIn` package gives you a pretty easy way to parallelize it (this assumes you have multiple cores on your machine or that you can set up a local cluster in one of the ways supported by the `parallel` package ...

```
library(parallel)
clust <- makeCluster(2,"PSOCK")
library(MuMIn)
```

Construct data:

```
set.seed(101)
x <- matrix(rnorm(300),ncol=3)
y <- x %*% c(1,2,3)+rnorm(100)
```

It will be easier to do this with a named data frame rather than an anonymous matrix:

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(y,x),c("y",paste0("x",1:3)))
```

The cluster nodes all need access to the data set:

```
clusterExport(clust,"df")
```

Fit the full model (you could use `y~.` to fit all variables)

```
full <- lm(y~x1+x2,data=df,na.action=na.fail)
```

Now fit all submodels (see `?MuMIn::dredge` for many more options to control which submodels are fitted)

```
p <- pdredge(full,cluster=clust)
coef(p)
##    (Intercept)        x1       x2
## 3 -0.003805107 0.7488708 2.590204
## 2 -0.028502039        NA 2.665305
## 1 -0.101434662 1.0490816       NA
## 0 -0.140451160        NA       NA
```