# Writing a Householder QR factorization function in R code

Tags: r, matrix, qr-decomposition

I am working on a piece of code to find the QR factorization of a matrix in R.

```
X <- structure(c(0.8147, 0.9058, 0.127, 0.9134, 0.6324, 0.0975, 0.2785, 
0.5469, 0.9575, 0.9649, 0.1576, 0.9706, 0.9572, 0.4854, 0.8003
), .Dim = c(5L, 3L))


myqr <- function(A) {
  n <- nrow(A)
  p <- ncol(A)
  Q <- diag(n)
  Inp <- diag(nrow = n, ncol = p)

  for(k in c(1:ncol(A))) {
    # extract the kth column of the matrix
    col<-A[k:n,k]
    # calculation of the norm of the column in order to create the vector
    norm1<-sqrt(sum(col^2))
    # Define the sign positive if a1 > 0 (-) else a1 < 0(+)  
    sign <- ifelse(col[1] >= 0, -1, +1)  
    # Calculate of the vector a_r
    a_r <- col - sign * Inp[k:n,k] * norm1
    # beta = 2 / ||a-r||^2  
    beta <- 2 / sum(t(a_r) %*% a_r)
    # the next line of code calculates the matrix Q in every step
    Q <- Q - beta *Q %*% c(rep(0,k-1),a_r) %*% t(c(rep(0,k-1),a_r))    
    # calculates the matrix R in each step
    A[k:n,k:p] <- A[k:n,k:p] - beta * a_r %*% t(a_r) %*% A[k:n,k:p]
    }

  list(Q=Q,R=A)
  }
```

But, Here I have not calculated in every step the matrix `H` that represents the householder reflection, also I have not calculated the matrix `A` in every step.

As `H = I - 2 v v'`, if I multiply by `Q` I obtain

```
QH = Q - 2 (Qv) v'    // multiplication on the left
HQ = Q - 2 v (Q'v)'    // multiplication on the right
```

Now, this operations should be work in every step. However if I consider the first matrix `H` and he the second matrix `H1`.... these matrices will be of smaller that the first one. In order to avoid that I have used the next line of code:

```
 Q <- Q - beta * Q %*% c(rep(0,k-1),a_r) %*% t(c(rep(0,k-1),a_r))
```

but, I am not sure why the code is working well, when I generate the new vector `a_r` with the first `k` entries of zeros at every step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought you want exactly the same output as returned by `qr.default`, which uses compact QR storage. But then I realized that you are storing `Q` and `R` factors separately.

Normally, QR factorization only forms `R` but not `Q`. In the following, I will describe QR factorization where both are formed. For those who lack basic understanding of QR factorization, please read this first: [lm(): What is qraux returned by QR decomposition in LINPACK / LAPACK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38741127/4891738), where there are neat math formulae arranged in LaTeX. In the following, I will assume that one knows what a Householder reflection is and how it is computed.

---

## QR factorization procedure

**First of all**, a Householder refection vector is `H = I - beta * v v'` (where `beta` is computed as in your code), not `H = I - 2 * v v'`.

**Then**, QR factorization `A = Q R` proceeds as `(Hp ... H2 H1) A = R`, where `Q = H1 H2 ... Hp`. To compute `Q`, we initialize `Q = I` (identity matrix), then multiply `Hk` on the right iteratively in the loop. To compute R, we initialize `R = A` and multiply `Hk` on the left iteratively in the loop.

**Now, at k-th iteration**, we have a **rank-1 matrix update** on `Q` and `A`:

```
Q := Q Hk = Q (I - beta v * v') = Q - (Q v) (beta v)'
A := Hk A = (I - beta v * v') A = A - (beta v) (A' v)'
```

`v = c(rep(0, k-1), a_r)`, where `a_r` is the reduced, non-zero part of a full reflection vector.

The code you have is doing such update in a brutal force:

```
Q <- Q - beta * Q %*% c(rep(0,k-1), a_r) %*% t(c(rep(0,k-1),a_r))
```

It first pads `a_r` to get the full reflection vector and performs the rank-1 update on the whole matrix. But actually we can drop off those zeros and write (do some matrix algebra if unclear):

```
Q[,k:n] <- Q[,k:n] - tcrossprod(Q[, k:n] %*% a_r, beta * a_r)
A[k:n,k:p] <- A[k:n,k:p] - tcrossprod(beta * a_r, crossprod(A[k:n,k:p], a_r))
```

so that only a fraction of `Q` and `A` are updated.

---

## Several other comments on your code

- You have used `t()` and `"%*%"` a lot! But almost all of them can be replaced by `crossprod()` or `tcrossprod()`. This eliminates the explicit transpose `t()` and is more memory efficient;
- You initialize another diagonal matrix `Inp` which is not necessary. To get householder reflection vector `a_r`, you can replace

  ```
  sign <- ifelse(col[1] >= 0, -1, +1)
  a_r <- col - sign * Inp[k:n,k] * norm1
  ```

  by

  ```
  a_r <- col; a_r[1] <- a_r[1] + sign(a_r[1]) * norm1
  ```

  where `sign` is an R base function.

---

## R code for QR factorization

```
## QR factorization: A = Q %*% R
## if `complete = FALSE` (default), return thin `Q`, `R` factor
## if `complete = TRUE`, return full `Q`, `R` factor

myqr <- function (A, complete = FALSE) {

  n <- nrow(A)
  p <- ncol(A)
  Q <- diag(n)

  for(k in 1:p) {
    # extract the kth column of the matrix
    col <- A[k:n,k]
    # calculation of the norm of the column in order to create the vector r
    norm1 <- sqrt(drop(crossprod(col)))
    # Calculate of the reflection vector a-r
    a_r <- col; a_r[1] <- a_r[1] + sign(a_r[1]) * norm1
    # beta = 2 / ||a-r||^2  
    beta <- 2 / drop(crossprod(a_r))
    # update matrix Q (trailing matrix only) by Householder reflection
    Q[,k:n] <- Q[,k:n] - tcrossprod(Q[, k:n] %*% a_r, beta * a_r)
    # update matrix A (trailing matrix only) by Householder reflection
    A[k:n, k:p] <- A[k:n, k:p] - tcrossprod(beta * a_r, crossprod(A[k:n,k:p], a_r))
    }

  if (complete) {
     A[lower.tri(A)] <- 0
     return(list(Q = Q, R = A))
     }
  else {
    R <- A[1:p, ]; R[lower.tri(R)] <- 0
    return(list(Q = Q[,1:p], R = R))
    }
  }
```

Now let's have a test:

```
X <- structure(c(0.8147, 0.9058, 0.127, 0.9134, 0.6324, 0.0975, 0.2785, 
0.5469, 0.9575, 0.9649, 0.1576, 0.9706, 0.9572, 0.4854, 0.8003
), .Dim = c(5L, 3L))

#       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
#[1,] 0.8147 0.0975 0.1576
#[2,] 0.9058 0.2785 0.9706
#[3,] 0.1270 0.5469 0.9572
#[4,] 0.9134 0.9575 0.4854
#[5,] 0.6324 0.9649 0.8003
```

First for thin-QR version:

```
## thin QR factorization
myqr(X)

#$Q
#            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
#[1,] -0.49266686 -0.4806678  0.17795345
#[2,] -0.54775702 -0.3583492 -0.57774357
#[3,] -0.07679967  0.4754320 -0.63432053
#[4,] -0.55235290  0.3390549  0.48084552
#[5,] -0.38242607  0.5473120  0.03114461
#
#$R
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] -1.653653 -1.1404679 -1.2569776
#[2,]  0.000000  0.9660949  0.6341076
#[3,]  0.000000  0.0000000 -0.8815566
```

Now the full QR version:

```
## full QR factorization
myqr(X, complete = TRUE)

#$Q
#            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
#[1,] -0.49266686 -0.4806678  0.17795345 -0.6014653 -0.3644308
#[2,] -0.54775702 -0.3583492 -0.57774357  0.3760348  0.3104164
#[3,] -0.07679967  0.4754320 -0.63432053 -0.1497075 -0.5859107
#[4,] -0.55235290  0.3390549  0.48084552  0.5071050 -0.3026221
#[5,] -0.38242607  0.5473120  0.03114461 -0.4661217  0.5796209
#
#$R
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] -1.653653 -1.1404679 -1.2569776
#[2,]  0.000000  0.9660949  0.6341076
#[3,]  0.000000  0.0000000 -0.8815566
#[4,]  0.000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
#[5,]  0.000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
```

Now let's check standard result returned by `qr.default`:

```
QR <- qr.default(X)

## thin R factor
qr.R(QR)
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] -1.653653 -1.1404679 -1.2569776
#[2,]  0.000000  0.9660949  0.6341076
#[3,]  0.000000  0.0000000 -0.8815566

## thin Q factor
qr.Q(QR)
#            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
#[1,] -0.49266686 -0.4806678  0.17795345
#[2,] -0.54775702 -0.3583492 -0.57774357
#[3,] -0.07679967  0.4754320 -0.63432053
#[4,] -0.55235290  0.3390549  0.48084552
#[5,] -0.38242607  0.5473120  0.03114461

## full Q factor
qr.Q(QR, complete = TRUE)
#            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
#[1,] -0.49266686 -0.4806678  0.17795345 -0.6014653 -0.3644308
#[2,] -0.54775702 -0.3583492 -0.57774357  0.3760348  0.3104164
#[3,] -0.07679967  0.4754320 -0.63432053 -0.1497075 -0.5859107
#[4,] -0.55235290  0.3390549  0.48084552  0.5071050 -0.3026221
#[5,] -0.38242607  0.5473120  0.03114461 -0.4661217  0.5796209
```

So our results are correct!