# How can I solve an allocate vector problem?

Tags: r, lm

Getting an error as cannot allocate vector of size 23628.3Gb while training a linear regression model with a dataset of around 1800000 observations and around 20 variables.

```
linear_reg_model = lm(target_variable ~., data = train_cleaned)
```

Comment: Do you have a lot of categorical variables with many levels? It's trying to allocate nearly 3TB of RAM. That seems a bit excessive. Are you sure your data has been read in correctly? How much RAM does your computer have?

Comment: 1.8M observations might be more than what you need to get a reliable regression. You might try taking repeated samples of a subset (say, 100k rows at a time) and see how much your results vary between them.

Comment: See here for related question on memory requirements of `lm` and strategies to address: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326853/why-does-lm-run-out-of-memory-while-matrix-multiplication-works-fine-for-coeffic

Comment: Ya, that suits me now.